# How to prove $|A\textbf{x}|\leq \|A\| |\textbf{x}|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I got in a problem in Rudin "Principles of mathematical analysis" in page 208, part (c). It says for $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$, define the norm $\|A\|$ of $A$ to be sup of all numbers $|A\textbf{x}|$, where $\textbf{x}$ ranges over all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $|\textbf{x}|\leq 1$. Now we have to prove
$|A\textbf{x}|\leq\|A\||\textbf{x}|$, $\forall \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to prove that but one $\sqrt{n}$ creates the problem.

Let, $|A\textbf{x}|^2=|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iA(e_i)|^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_iA(e_i)|)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i| |A(e_i)|)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2)(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|A(e_k)|^2)=|\textbf{x}|^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n}|A(e_k)|^2$.

Now, $|e_k|=1$ so, $|A(e_k)|\leq \|A\|$. Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}|A(e_k)|^2 \leq n\|A\|^2$ which gives $|A\textbf{x}|\leq \sqrt{n}\|A\||\textbf{x}|$.

So, how to get rid of this $\sqrt{n}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **HINT**:  $\mathbf x = |\mathbf x|\dfrac{\mathbf x}{|\mathbf x|}$ for $\mathbf x\ne \mathbf 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to take the square or use matrix multiplication. This is completely formal: Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$, with $x\neq 0$. Then $\left\lvert\frac x{\lvert x\rvert}\right\rvert = 1$ and hence
$$
\frac1{\lvert x\rvert}\cdot \lvert Ax\rvert = \left\lvert A\frac x{\lvert x\rvert}\right\rvert \le \lVert A\rVert.
$$
Multiplying by $\lvert x\rvert$ gives $\lvert Ax\rvert \le \lVert A\rVert\cdot \lvert x\rvert$. Obviously, this inequality also holds for $x=0$ and hence for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: There is no need to assume $|x|\leq 1$.

Comment: Ah sorry. I will change it. Thanks!

Comment: @user218931 Thank you very much, its much easier than I thought

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier than that. Assume $x\neq 0$, and let $\lambda=1/|x|$. Then by definition of $\|A\|$, we have
$$
|A(\lambda x)|\leq \|A\|\cdot |\lambda x|
$$
Now pull the $\lambda$ out, and cancel it, and you're done.